# How to popup success message in same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that contains `modal`, in the modal there is a form, in this form i am inserting some data in the database, i want to show popup success message after insertion and to be on the same page again and to empty the form inputs in the modal.

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="AddNewFarmer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <!----Form Inputs--->
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
if($result->execute()) 
{   
?>
<script language="javascript">
      alert("Record inserted successfully");
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What it's not working ?

Comment: The question is how to keep the modal opened after submitting the form and popup the success message

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('myform').reset();`

put an ID in your forms like `id="myform"` and use the above js code.

So basically

```
<form id="myform" action="AddNewFarmer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <!----Form Inputs--->
</form>
<script language="javascript">
    alert("Record inserted successfully");
    document.getElementById('myform').reset();
</script>
```

If you dont want the page to return back to its original index instead of `AddNewFarmer.php`, you can return back to the original page like this.

```
?>
// after you save
return header('Location: yourfilename.php');
?>
```

Comment: i need also to keep the modal opened not to be on the page that have done the code `AddNewFarmer.php`

Comment: so why not close the model ?

Comment: Oh I get it, you mean that you want to keep your form model open?

Comment: ok at least close the modal but be in the main page that contains the modal not `AddNewFarmer.php`

Comment: @Bnabil okay, so how that is done is that, when you do a action of post to `AddNewFarmer.php` php makes the whole site load, there is two ways to solve this.
1) Use javascript ajax to save your information
2) when the `AddNewFarmer.php` saves your information, have a return call back to your original page.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

*Just use this function and css in your page*

*Javascript*

```
function snackbar(name,classd){

if ($('#snackbar').length == 0) {
  $("body").append('<div id="snackbar"></div><div style="display:none;" id="overlay"></div>');
}
  $("#snackbar").removeClass().html(name).addClass("show").addClass(classd);setTimeout(function(){$("#snackbar").removeClass("show");},2500 );
}
```

*CSS*

```
#snackbar {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Hidden by default. Visible on click */
  max-width: 250px;
  /* Set a default minimum width */
  background-color: #333;
  /* Black background color */
  color: #000;
  /* White text color */
  text-align: center;
  /* Centered text */
  border-radius: 2px;
  /* Rounded borders */
  padding: 16px;
  /* Padding */
  position: fixed;
  /* Sit on top of the screen */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Add a z-index if needed */
  right: 0;
  /* Center the snackbar */
  top: 60px
  /* 30px from the bottom */ }

/* Show the snackbar when clicking on a button (class added with JavaScript) */
/* line 54, styles.scss */
#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible;
  /* Show the snackbar */
  /* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar. 
  However, delay the fade out process for 2.5 seconds */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s; }

/* Animations to fade the snackbar in and out */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0; }
  to {
    top: 90px;
    opacity: 1; } }
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0; }
  to {
    top: 60px;
    opacity: 1; } }
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    top: 60px;
    opacity: 1; }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 1; }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0; } }
/* line 83, styles.scss */
.error {
  background: #ff4c4d !important; }

/* line 86, styles.scss */
.success {
  background: #71e8a4 !important; }
```

## Use this function where You want

```
<?php 
snackbar('please Enter All Details','error');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the jquery file in the Head

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

you need little bit knowledge about Ajax which will send the data and get the data without reloading the page in order to understand this and you have to put `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the reload

```
<script>
function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Button_id_submit").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var formdata = jQuery("#YourformId").serialize();
       $.ajax({
           url: "Your_preferred.php",
           type:"POST",
           data:formdata,
           });
        });
    alert("Record inserted successfully");
    document.getElementById('Your_form_ID').reset();
   });
 }
</script>
```